# Export same function from C++ dll under different names and different addresses with Remove Redundant COMDATs enabled

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++

I am working on `Excel XLL Addin` that requires functions to be exported by name. For my requirements I need two exported functions to call the same function internally.
Like this :

```
LPXLOPER WINAPI func1(...)
{
   return MyFunc();
} 
LPXLOPER WINAPI func2(...)
{
   return MyFunc();
}
```

When `Remove Redundant COMDATs (/OPT:ICF)` option is specified in the linker optimization options, the functions exports are pointing to the same address. This is unacceptable, because Excel caches the address so the`addin` does not work as required.

Is there any option rather than adding dummy
 parameter to internal function in order to prevent this?

Comment: Mysterious.  Why not just change the linker option?

Comment: why would excel fail because two functions happened to share the same address? func1 and func2 are both exported symbols right?

Comment: The problem is that they should be published to Excel as different functions taking different parameters. If they share the same address Excel gets confused and uses the same wizard signature for every one of them.